# Condition for integer solution of equation $a x+by=c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Equation $127 x+35 y=a$ has infinite solutions because Euclidean algorithm gives :

$$127\times 8 -35\times 29=1$$

first condition: $(127, 35)=1$

Second condition:$127\times 8 -35\times 29=1$

And general form of solutions are:

$x=35 t + 127 a$

$y=-127 t +29 a$; $a, t∈Z$

But equation $ 86x+35y=28$ has no integer solution because we have:

$86=2\times 35+16$

$35=2\times 16 +3$

$16=3\times 5+1$

and $35\times 5-86\times 2 =3$

and $c= 28$ is not divisible by 3.

That is $(a, b)=1$ is necessary but is not sufficient condition .Am I right? If not what is wrong here?

Comment: A necessary condition is that $c$ must be divisible by $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$. If this happens then you need $\frac{a}{\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)}x+\frac{b}{\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)}y=\frac{c}{\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)}$ has solutions. Since $\frac{a}{\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)}$ and $\frac{b}{\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)}$ are relatively prime, then $\frac{a}{\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)}x+\frac{b}{\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)}y=1$ has solutions. Multiplying them by $\frac{c}{\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)}$ you get solutions of the original equation.

Comment: The linear Diophantine equation $ax+by=c$ has a solution iff $(a,b) \mid c.$

Comment: $86\times11-35\times27=1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson,Thank you, could you please say how did you find 11 and 27?

Comment: "Extended Euclidean Algorithm." Look it up, or search this website for it – it has been discussed many, many times here.

Comment: $11×5 - 27×2 =1.$

Answer (score 2):

$\gcd(a,b) = 1$ is not necessary. e.g. there are infinite number of integer solutions for

$$2x + 4y = 0$$

As user647486 mentioned in comment, a necessary condition is that $\gcd(a,b)\mid c$.

Otherwise, if $\gcd(a,b)\not\mid c$, $\gcd(a,b)$ divides the left hand side of $ax + by = c$ but not the right hand side. This leads to contradiction.

(e.g. there are no integer solutions for $2x+4y = 1$)

---

In general, to solve these equation where $c = c'\gcd(a,b)$:

$$ax + by = c' \gcd(a,b)$$

Find $m,n\in \mathbb Z$ using extended Euclidean algorithm such that

$$am + bn = \gcd(a,b)$$

Multiply both sides by $c'$ to get

$$a(mc') + b(nc') = c'\gcd(a,b)$$

So $(x = mc', y = nc')$ is an integer solution.

For other solutions, if $ax+by = ax'+by' = c$, then

$$\begin{align*}
a(x'-x)+b(y'-y) &= 0\\
\frac a{\gcd(a,b)}(x'-x) &= -\frac b{\gcd(a,b)}(y'-y)
\end{align*}$$

$\frac a{\gcd(a,b)}$ and $\frac b{\gcd(a,b)}$ are coprime, and so

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
x' &= x + \frac b{\gcd(a,b)}t = mc' + \frac b{\gcd(a,b)}t\\
y' &= y - \frac a{\gcd(a,b)}t = nc' - \frac a{\gcd(a,b)}t\\
\end{align*}\right.$$

Comment: In my question $(a, b)=1|c$ and extended Euclidean algorithm shows that there always exist numbers $x_1$ and $y_1$ such that $a x_1-by_1=1$.everything is now clear for me. Thank you all.